# Error Check for scanf using while loops?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, error-checking

I've been trying to do an error check for my program, for scanf using a while loop, but I am unsure of how to do this.

I want to make sure the user inputs between 4 and 8 for number of judges, and the score doesn't go below 0 or above 10.

could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i,j,k, judges;
float max, min,total;

int main(){
   max = 0.0;
   min = 10.0;
   judges = 0;
   total = 0;

printf("Enter number of judges between 4-8: ");
scanf("%d", &judges);

    float scores[judges];

for(i = 0; i < judges; i++){
    printf("Enter a score for judge %d : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%5f", &scores[i]);
}
for(j = 0; j < judges; j++){
    if(min > scores[j]){
        min = scores[j];
    }
    if (max < scores[j]){
        max = scores[j];
    }
}
for(k = 0; k < judges; k++){
    total = total + scores[k];
}
total = total-max-min;
printf("max = %4.1f    min = %4.1f    total = total = %4.1f", min,   max,total);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// for judge
while (1) {
    printf("Enter number of judges between 4-8: ");
    scanf("%d", &judges);
    if (judges >= 4 && judges <= 8)
        break;
    else
        puts("Judge out of range of 4 and 8.");
}

// for socres
for(i = 0; i < judges; i++){
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a score for judge %d : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%5f", &scores[i]);
        if (scores[i] >= 0.0 && scores[I] <= 10.0)
            break;
        else
            puts("score out of range of 0.0 and 10.0");
}
```

Comment: Good to know it helped, chose it as accept answer :) thanks

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to know what the use of puts is? Im new to c and trying to learn :) thanks.

Comment: @Bronson `puts` print it's string argument and a new line, so `puts("foo");` is the same as `printf("foo\n");`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use do-while loops around the areas that you are checking.  If the condition (in the while part) is not met, the loop will repeat and the user will be prompted again.

```
do{
    printf("Enter number of judges between 4-8: ");
    scanf("%d", &judges);
}while(judges < 4 || judges > 8);
```